# Bootstrap Carousel same height items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the general bootstrap carousel but included 2 columns per slides. I am trying to make the carousel slides all be the same height. So if one slide has more content the other slides with adjust to this height:

```
<div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="5000">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-xl-6 align-self-center">
                test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="carousel-item white" data-bs-interval="5000">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-xl-6 align-self-center">
                test
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-6">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    

  </div>
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
  
</div>
```

I have tried the following jQuery code but it does not seem to work when checking on mobile:

```
<script>
function carouselNormalization() {
  var items = $('#carouselExampleInterval .item'),
    heights = [],
    tallest;

  if (items.length) {
    function normalizeHeights() {
      items.each(function() { 
        heights.push($(this).height());
      });
      tallest = Math.max.apply(null, heights); 
      items.each(function() {
        $(this).css('min-height', tallest + 'px');
      });
    };
    normalizeHeights();

    $(window).on('resize orientationchange', function() {
      tallest = 0, heights.length = 0; 
      items.each(function() {
        $(this).css('min-height', '0');
      });
      normalizeHeights();
    });
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  carouselNormalization();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Check this: https://codepen.io/mohan-aiyer/pen/MzgvbN.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the following bootstrap, your container will scale all of your carousel items to the height of the item with most content.

Bootstrap 4 h-100 class for height:100% and container-fluid to expand the viewport ;

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
```

to replace

```
<div class ="container">
```

Full html with change and example:

```
<section style="background:#f7f7f7;" class="py-5">

<div class="container-fluid h-100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
<div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade parab" data-ride="carousel">
  
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <h3>Sunil Radhakrishnan<br><small>Bengaluru</small></h3>
      <p>Working with Mahadevan is just what I needed to get reignited and fired up about my career which was just prodding. I am so grateful!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <p>asdasd</p> <p>asdasd</p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non gravida turpis. Praesent consequat lacus eu ipsum pellentesque, et eleifend arcu bibendum. Donec vel leo in ex volutpat dapibus. Praesent eget lectus pulvinar, porta arcu quis, volutpat nulla. Vestibulum id tellus sit amet ligula egestas faucibus eget et erat. Aliquam placerat, quam vel fringilla rutrum, dui justo dictum mauris, at egestas risus eros vel ligula. Fusce sagittis convallis velit at ornare. Integer maximus, nulla sit amet cursus efficitur, nibh sem euismod elit, eget euismod mauris eros in mauris. Aliquam bibendum bibendum urna eu auctor.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non gravida turpis. Praesent consequat lacus eu ipsum pellentesque, et eleifend arcu bibendum. Donec vel leo in ex volutpat dapibus. Praesent eget lectus pulvinar, porta arcu quis, volutpat nulla. Vestibulum id tellus sit amet ligula egestas faucibus eget et erat. Aliquam placerat, quam vel fringilla rutrum, dui justo dictum mauris, at egestas risus eros vel ligula. Fusce sagittis convallis velit at ornare. Integer maximus, nulla sit amet cursus efficitur, nibh sem euismod elit, eget euismod mauris eros in mauris. Aliquam bibendum bibendum urna eu auctor.</p>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non gravida turpis. Praesent consequat lacus eu ipsum pellentesque, et eleifend arcu bibendum. Donec vel leo in ex volutpat dapibus. Praesent eget lectus pulvinar, porta arcu quis, volutpat nulla. Vestibulum id tellus sit amet ligula egestas faucibus eget et erat. Aliquam placerat, quam vel fringilla rutrum, dui justo dictum mauris, at egestas risus eros vel ligula. Fusce sagittis convallis velit at ornare. Integer maximus, nulla sit amet cursus efficitur, nibh sem euismod elit, eget euismod mauris eros in mauris. Aliquam bibendum bibendum urna eu auctor.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</section>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/0ytL5g1s/2/

UPDATED #2:
Working example with 2 column using flex: https://jsfiddle.net/a3dk8th4/

Comment: I tried to add h-100 to my container and it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you also add container-fluid?
<div class="container-fluid h-100">

Comment: @Emanuel I have included a JSFiddle above to a working example. The first and second item are now the same height as the third - which I have added a couple of additional lines of filler text to push the size.

Comment: Yes your example seems to work but when I try to implement it I don't get the same results. Im wondering if it's due the columns.

Comment: Have provided another working example, with 2 columns 3rd item. Good luck!